# A SDK can contain front end?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I have a sdk for android, in the documentation of the sdk is indicate that it contains some screens that must be mandatory calling  a specífic method but I only see a
.aar and an .xml (layout).

I was able to install the sdk with android studio and I only see the different methods.

It is assumed that for the functionality of the sdk it has a front end and a sound that is mandatory when we got a good response calling some specific methods . My question must be is if I should develop that or does the sdk include it. knowing that the sdk only contains an .aar and a xml. no images or sound that must meet.

Someone can clarify this to me?

Edit: .aar*

Comment: `.aab` files OR `.aar` file.`AAB` is Android App Bundle which for [Google Play Store app publishing](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle), `AAR` is Android Archive file which is a [library file](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) containing code/resources/android manifest for merging into an android project. As how to make your specific SDK work what does the SDK documentation say. Check if there is a sample app and look there.

Comment: This is something that the SDK documentation needs to tell you.